# LINQ to SQL DBML Semantic Model

Tags: linq-to-sql

I'm planning to write an tool which would import `dbml` file and spit out an [MDL](http://code.google.com/p/octalforty-wizardby/wiki/MdlReference) file for migration purposes and such. To do this, I obviously have to read this `dbml` file into some kind of semantic model to do transformations.

I tried to use `XmlMappingSource`, but first it failed because it expects the XML namespace of a file to be `http://schemas.microsoft.com/linqtosql/mapping/2007`, whereas I had `http://schemas.microsoft.com/linqtosql/dbml/2007`. After I changed the namespace to read `.../mapping/2007`, `XmlMappingSource` started to complain about all kinds of unrecognized attributes.

Is there any object model to represent the structure of a `dbml` file?

Answer (score 0):

Being no expert, but having had somewhat of the same problem...

When validating dbml files, XmlMappingSource uses (I think...at least close ;-)
DbmlSchema.xsd, so perhaps either tamper with the existing one, or make you own
mappingsource?

This [article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb882675.aspx) may help (or may not...not quite sure I get your question)